# magento ups shipping api

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, ups

> I want to calculate shipping rate using UPS api in magento.

```
I will pass lenght, width, height and zipcode the UPS api will return shipping rate for that product.
```

I got the UPS rating API that will calculate the shipping rate from the below url after you login.

https://www.ups.com/upsdeveloperkit/downloadresource?loc=en_US

The development guide shows we can implement this using xml or SOAP call.

> Can anyone tell me how exactly can I implement this in magento if
>   possible explain it at coding level.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to code your own api access. Just use the ootb UPS core extension.

1. Goto class `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Ups`
2. Goto line 907 (something like that) and change the part from

> ```
> <Package>
>   <PackagingType><Code>{$params['48_container']}</Code></PackagingType>
>   <PackageWeight>
>      <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>{$r->getUnitMeasure()}</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
>     <Weight>{$params['23_weight']}</Weight>
>   </PackageWeight>
> </Package>
> ```

to

> ```
> <Package>
>   <PackagingType><Code>{$params['48_container']}</Code></PackagingType>
>     <Dimensions>
>               <UnitOfMeasurement>
>                   <Code>CM</Code>
>               </UnitOfMeasurement>
>               <Length>30</Length>
>               <Width>30</Width>
>               <Height>30</Height>
>   </Dimensions>
>   <PackageWeight>
>      <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>{$r->getUnitMeasure()}</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
>     <Weight>{$params['23_weight']}</Weight>
>   </PackageWeight>
> </Package>
> ```

Just use some variables to change 30 to whatever you want. It works, i tried it!

Good luck!

Comment: Can I use the same API to calculate estimated delivery dates as well, or I need separate API in magento. If I need separate API then please guide me which API can I use and How to integrate it in magento.

Comment: hey Mischa Leiss It not working in my case I substituted the the lines as indicated above now it is not showing all the active shipping methods only.Please guide how to proceed

Comment: does it work without the lines added? have you configured the ups extension correctly (api key, user id, pass etc...)?

i guess its not working in general, so it would be best to make it working without the changes from above, cause they wont do any harm to the code when inserted correctly!

Comment: Actually above code worked after removing  <UnitOfMeasurement<Code>CM</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>  this line. Now I am not able to decide the shipping rate which it is returning is correct or not. I searched through google and I got to know using lenght width and height we have to calculate dimensional weight. then comparison is made between dimensional weight and actual weight which ever is greater will be used for billing. Is above method calculating shipping rate using the same technique. Please reply and any idea about how can I calculate multibox shipping.